# Can't Update MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my little update code is giving me an error message that I can't work out how to resolve it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

     include('dbconfig.php');
     $con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()) ; 

     if (!$con){
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
        mysql_select_db($db, $con);

       function sqlEscape($string){     
          return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."'";
       }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $q  =  "UPDATE records SET `name` = " + sqlEscape($_POST['name']) + ", 
    `age` = " + sqlEscape($_POST['age']) + ", 
    `location` = " + sqlEscape($_POST['location']) + ", 
    `telephone` = " + sqlEscape($_POST['telephone']) + "

     WHERE id = $_POST[id]";                

     mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

     }                  
  ?>
```

Here's the error message it prints out:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
```

Can someone see where I'm going wrong at all?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Echo your `$q` variable and post the results. At first glance it looks like you need single quotes around your values (`name = whatever` needs to be `name = 'whatever'`).

Comment: @LoganSerman His sqlEscape function takes care of that

Comment: Good call, I skipped over the body of that function. Still, post the result of echoing `$q`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$q  =  "UPDATE records SET `name` = " . sqlEscape($_POST['name']) . ", 
    `age` = " . sqlEscape($_POST['age']) . ", 
    `location` = " . sqlEscape($_POST['location']) . ", 
    `telephone` = " . sqlEscape($_POST['telephone']) . "

     WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
```

Use "." instead of "+" to concat strings in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, let me try your suggestion and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding strings together with the `+` operator, which is for adding numbers. In PHP, strings are concatenated with the `.` (period) operator.

```
$q = "UPDATE records SET `name` = " . sqlEscape(...) . ",
```

etc

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the + and see if it makes any difference.